# How do I restore 2 in app purchases depending on the purchase made?

Tags: in-app-purchase, restore

How do I restore 2 in app purchases that have been paid for, after using this method: 
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];  -> depending on the purchase paid for

Answer (score 0):

For this answer i assume you have successfully implemented the purchase.

In the method "paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:" that you must implement for the in app purchase, you iterate over all transactions.

From a restored SKPaymentTransaction, you can access the originalTransaction (it's a property), and do the same you did when the user first purchased.